# How can I attach an EventListener to an EventSource in another process?

Tags: c#, trace, system.diagnostics

I'm trying to attach a listener to a running process which uses an [`EventSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource.aspx) to trace processing events. I've gotten as far as creating my own listener by inheriting from [`EventListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventlistener.aspx) and (presumably) need to call [`EnableEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventlistener.enableevents.aspx) to begin receiving information.

The first argument to all the overloads is the `EventSource` to configure and send messages from, but I am unclear how to compose that instance when it needs to identify a source of events in the external process.

I'm just knocking this together as a proof-of-concept, so the code runs in a Console application and the `TestEventListener` just tries to write the event to the Console window.

```
EventSource source = null;

using (var listener = new TestEventListener())
{
    listener.EnableEvents(source, EventLevel.Verbose);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the EventListener class does not talk cross-process, or even across AppDomains. That wasn't the purpose of the EventListener class.

Instead, I recommend you use the upcoming (and most likely will be the official supported ETW "reader" library from MSFT) --

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent

While you're at it, check out -- http://oculus.codeplex.com/ (this is very similar to TraceEvent, but has a bunch of different generate code special windows events)